# Nodejs + Express + mysql callback issue

Tags: node.js, express, callback

I 'm having some trouble understanding the behavior of callbacks .
For example, the following code does not work as expected cos callbacks .
I tried async library but without obtaining the desired behavior.

```
module.exports.list = function ( req, res ) {
    model.list( id, idx, function( boo ){
       async.forEachOf( boo, function ( b, k, e ) {
            model.sublist( b.text, function( foo ) {
               b.foo = foo;
            })
       })
       res.json({ data : boo }) //boo dont have foo porperty
    });
};

model.list = execute some big mysql query, and return rows (boo is an array).
model.sublist = same as model.list
```

Edit Solution:

```
module.exports.list = function ( req, res ) {
    model.list( id, idx, function( boo ){
        async.forEachOf( boo, function ( b, k, e ) {
            model.sublist( b.text, function( foo ) {
               b.foo = foo;
               e();
            })
        })
        res.json({ data : boo })
    });
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Should move `res.json(...)` into 2nd callback, after `model.sublist`

Comment: The reason WHY node frameworks give you a response object that you can send messages on instead of having your function return a value (the way frameworks usually work in other languages) is exactly so that you can get data asynchronously and THEN send a response. So just send the response at the correct place, not before you receive it.

Comment: boo is an array, for each intem inside boo y need to execute some query based on boo item.text

Answer (score 2):

should call response only in 2nd callback. [read async documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachOf)

```
 module.exports.list = function ( req, res ) {
    model.list( id, idx, function( boo ){
       async.forEachOf( boo, function ( b, k, e ) {
            model.sublist( b.text, function( foo ) {
               b.foo = foo;
            });
            e();
       },function(){
           res.json({ data : boo }) //boo dont have foo porperty
       });
    });
 }
```

Comment: e() is executed before sublist callback ends, so b.foo = undefined , how i can achieve this?